# ListView. Check Count of Items and change Visibility

Tags: listview, mvvm-light, observablecollection, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a Winrt application using MVVM.
I have a ListView with a binding to a ObservableCollection.

```
 <ListView x:Name="TestListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}" Visibility="{Binding ListVis, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}".../>
```

My ObservableCollection:

```
public class SearchResultCollection : ObservableCollection<TestData>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
    {

 public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
        {
            var res =  AsyncInfo.Run(async c =>
                                              {
                                                 //ask about data from server
                                                  return new LoadMoreItemsResult() {Count = PAGE_SIZE};

                                              });

            return res;
        }

}
```

I also have TextBox with linked RelayCommand (executes on event "TextChanged"):

```
Search = new RelayCommand<BehaviorEventArgs>((e) =>
            {
                dynamic sender = e.Sender;
                string text = sender.Text;
                _searchText = text;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    TestItems= null;                   
                    return;
                }
                ListVis = false; 
                TestItems= new SearchResultCollection(_searchService, text);
                ((ObservableCollection<TestData>)Contacts).CollectionChanged += SearchViewModel_CollectionChanged;


            });

 void SearchViewModel_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ObservableCollection<Contact>)sender).Count != 0)
            {
                ListVis = true;
            }

        }
```

I'm trying to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209102/466545, but when  the Visibility of ListView get state Collapsed the CollectionChanged is not fired anymore. When i remove the Visibility property and check the work without it, the CollectionChanged event fires like needed.

Comment: I recommend you to try the width and height of ListView control to 0 on behalf of Collapsed visibility. You will need additional Converter or code-behind works, but may work fine. I cannot say definitely, but WinRT may not fire some events performance related issue. Likewise, please note that default WinRT binding is Mode=Oneway, not TwoWay.

Comment: Thanks.I tryed with Opacity property and it works!